# How to fix "Unresolve reference" in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.R
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    val activity_btn = mainbtn

    activity_btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent(this, activity_main2::class.java)

        startActivity(intent)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
         })
    }

}
```

I have tried clean project,reopening project,rebuild project etc but none of these have worked.

It says Unresolved reference:activity_main,slide_in_right,slide_out_left etc.

Comment: You've imported `android.R` instead of R-class of your project?

Comment: hi,did put `slide_in_right,slide_out_left` in anim foloder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove line import android.R; from your code and rebuild again